# Bind variable to Node request lifecycle

Tags: node.js, request, global, page-lifecycle

For each request from a client, there is a specific set of constants that have to be created/queried, and then get used multiple times until the response gets sent.

However, as they get used about everywhere and the codebase is already quite big, I've noticed that these variables just get queried/created multiple times throughout the request instead of being passed along everywhere.

To be fair, passing them along as arguments everywhere would make the code quite cluttered, though.

I'm not an expert of the Node request lifecycle, however I know that I can't just set up these variables in the global scope, as their values differ for each request (although they stay constant throughout the request), and would thus get applied to every request at once.

Therefore, my question is as follows - what would be the smartest way of binding a bunch of variables to a specific request context, meaning that the codebase can access them from pretty much anywhere, similar to a global, but yet only access the value specific to the current request the code is being executed for?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What framework are you using? Just plain `http.Server`?

Comment: @slebetman We're using express

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking something to have in execution context and there is one node library can do this for you. I am using where i need to use those set object down the line in modules or even update down the line.

[Node zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js#readme)

You can get something like this, `Zone.current.get(MyName.MyRequestContext).userResourceData;`

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll check it out, thank you very much!

Comment: Check that. I am  pretty much sure that will help you. If you are happy with answers please upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use private variable in a file and can have getter and setter function for that variable.
you can change or access that variable value in every node request as per your requirement.

Hope I understood the question right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't think this resolves the problem: If I just have a private variable somewhere, I will need to pass it down every single method chain of my code (which is impossible as I don't control the whole codebase anyway). If I make it global, that variable will be the same across all requests. I basically want a global variable *bound to each individual request*

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what middlewares are for. In Express, middlewares exploit the fact that in javascript object properties are not static and does not have to obey what is defined in its class.

For example, the following is a middleware that extracts request body and parse it as JSON:

```
function jsonBodyparser (req, res, next) {
    let rawData = '';

    req.on('data', bytes => {
        rawData += bytes.toString()
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
        req.body = JSON.parse(rawData);
        next(); // continue processing
    });
}
```

Similarly, you can implement any common logic as middlewares:

```
function commonLogic (req, res, next) {
    // set common variables as properties of req or res:

    req.geoIP = getGeoIP(req);
    getUser().then(user => {
        req.language = user.preferences.language;

        // set variables you want to pass to templating engines
        // such as handlebars or ejs in res.locals:

        res.locals.username = user.name;
        res.locals.role = user.role;

        next(); // remember to call next() when you're done!
    });
}
```

You can use it like any other middleware. Express has a very flexible middleware architecture:

```
// use it globally:
app.use(commonLogic);

// use it on some sub-path:
app.use('/some/path/*',commonLogic);

// use it on one end-point:
app.get('/some/path/to/endpoint', commonLogic, (req, res) => {
    // ...
    res.send('some response');
});

// use it with a router:
var router = express.Router();
router.use(commonLogic);
```